# Do we need to consider woofer physical volume while calculating box

Tags: bass, subwoofer, sub-bass

I am trying to create a subwoofer box enclosure on https://subbox.pro/ website. The subwoofer I picked is `JBL A1500Hi`. As per the manual, the volume of the box should be 28.32 Liters. So should I consider adding the physical volume of the subwoofer?

Answer (score 0):

As per the instructions on that site, the volume of the enclosure ignores the speaker itself. It is simply the internal dimensions of the enclosure.